# What does exactly depend on the character rarity?

Tags: genshin-impact

Is there any difference between 4-star and 5-star characters?
I mean, the drop rate is different, sure and I see the difference in a quality of animations (or that's my imagination?), but **is there a practical difference like damage and stuff like that?**

Comment: Stars = rarity. Think of weapon refining or constellatins, you need lots of $$ to do those often with 5-stars and most free-players won't have even one of some.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

5* characters have better base stats on average than 4* characters:

| Rarity | HP Avg | ATK Avg | DEF Avg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5* | 10434.14 | 257.86 | 676.57 |
| 4* | 8911.5 | 244 | 653.71 |

I've got base numbers from [this spreadsheet with all characters stats on 80 lvl](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1B14gSBGJvGZDum-Z6Gpy1ruIHPPGzY-ZsiNsMIiFTgE/edit#gid=295490104), then excluded Traveller (because we cannot get it from Wishes) and did simple average (sum / # of characters).

On average difference is not that big, but let's compare some specific characters - 2 best DPS from each rarity:

| Character | ATK |
| --- | --- |
| 5* Diluc | 295 |
| 5* Keqing | 285 |
| 4* Fischl | 216 |
| 4* Razor | 207 |

Clearly 5* DPS beat their 4* counterparts by their most important stat.

In theory, constellations for 4* are more easily obtainable and should offset any initial stats difference, but in reality 4* character pool is bigger, meaning you will receive a lot of constellations for characters you don't play.

Comment: I don't think it's fair to directly compare those characters unless they have the same substat. Its like how some 4* weapons have higher base damage values than others but it's solely dependent on their substats

Comment: @sayu actually base stats is the only thing we could compare right now - everything else is different - used weapons, elements, secondary stats, cooldowns, energy costs, etc. The point of my answer was to show that at least in some aspect 5* are better

Answer (score 6):

There is no difference between 4* and 5* characters, asides from their gacha pull rarity.

People may mistakenly assume that 5* are more powerful than 4*.  "Powerful" is an extremely subjective term because of how many different aspects characters can be viewed from, whether it be their base stats, or their relevance in the Spiral Abyss, or for overworld exploration.

Comment: If "powerful" is indeed extremely subjective, are people still mistaken in the stated assumption?

Comment: To be specific here, a c0 5* will probably, in general, be stronger than a c0 4* (but not always). However, it's very common for c1, c2, and especially a c6 4* to be stronger than a c0 5*. Power is fairly relative and depends more on how the character is developed than their rarity.

Comment: > c0 5* will probably, in general, be stronger than a c0 4* Not true, as I mentioned previously in my answer, saying "stronger" means nothing when there are a wide variety of criteria to judge a character's power.  Venti is strong due to his CC, whereas Sucrose offers a weaker version of CC in exchange for a boost to the team's elemental mastery.  Each character has tradeoffs and no character is a direct upgrade over one another.

Comment: It would be like saying "Diluc is stronger than Barbara". Well yes, combat-wise, but Barbara is stronger than Diluc at healing.  Then Venti is stronger than Barbara at CC. But Fischl is a better bow user than Venti  -- ad infinitum.   Comparing 5* and 4* directly makes little sense unless they both have the same weapon slot and fill the same exact role...

Comment: Doesn't this mean that then 4* characters are preferable for f2p than 5*, since you can level them more?

Comment: @klm123 In a sense yes, because you're more likely to pull 4* heroes more often than 5* heroes out of banners. I don't understand what you mean by "level them more"? Do you mean you can get upgraded constellations? 4* and 5* characters have the same max level cap of 90, there is no difference.